# How to apply style on svg path in d3js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

As I am trying to create horizon chart based on multi year data. I have a query regarding "how to apply style on svg path in d3js to control color based on data?

Fiddle is shared at http://jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1/

Here, I am able to apply colors on svg but I want to apply actual on path using g element.

May be like below code:

```
path.enter().append("path")
            .transition()
            .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d); })
            .attr("transform", t0)
            .attr("d", d0);
```

Comment: Hi Gerardo, could you please tell me what is not clear in my question, i will do my best to clarify. Pls suggest. data structure used is- {Date: MMDDYYYY , Value: 0.01~3.0}. I am using this URL: gist.github.com/syntagmatic/7612dd3c35eeddf51a0b as reference code.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to:

```
  lineGraph
    .data([newValue])
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d); })
```

Now only the color of the path is changing, if that was your question

Comment: Thanks Dane ! NO, my question is about: why same logic works on svg but not on path?

Comment: which logic is not working on path ? I don't get you ??

Comment: .attr('fill', function(d) { return color(d); }) 
where     var color =   d3.scale.threshold()
         .domain([0,1])
          .range(["green", "yellow", "red"]);

Comment: I think it's working. changing `svg` to `lineGraph` still maps values 2 -> red, 1 -> green and 0.5 -> yellow

Comment: I am using this URL: http://gist.github.com/syntagmatic/7612dd3c35eeddf51a0b to generate horizon chart and want to control color same as fiddle at jsfiddle.net/pjrc0yy3/1. Your help will be highly appreciated